# Replacing multiple CSS style strings with sed

Tags: css, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I've been trying to figure out how I can replace certain strings contained within CSS files that contain the same CSS variable string that I wish to replace throughout multiple files at once using Bash, to avoid the tedious task of having to open up each instance of CSS file in each directory just to replace certain strings within those CSS files.

in my CSS files I want to comment out certain lines in the CSS code, but I'm having trouble escaping certain characters and convert that line with a commented out line, ie; `outline-style: dashed;` with `/*outline-style: dashed;*/`

I can't figure out how to escape the `:` and `;` characters as well as the following for commenting out lines `/* */` what I've tried so far but hasn't worked for me was the following by using xargs with perl;

```
find . -type f | xargs perl -e 's/outline-style dashed;/\/*outline-style dashed;*/\/g;'
```

but this returns an error saying

```
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/outline-
style dashed;/\/*outline-style dashed;*/\"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/outline-style dashed;/\/*outline-
style dashed;*/\"
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
xargs: perl: exited with status 255; aborting
```

I also tried with using sed which seem to work for most simple of replacements by trying with

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/$^outline-style\: dotted\;/\/*outline-style\: dotted\;/g' *.{css} \;
```

but this doesn't quite work, this just returns errors saying `sed: can't read *.{css}: No such file or directory`

I tried without adding the `*.{css}` in there but still gives me same errors, but with no output changes to any of the CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have directories ending with .css, you can use this:

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -i 's/^outline-style: dashed;$/\/*outline-style: dashed;*\//' **/*.css
```

Or you can edit your `find` example like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.css' -exec sed -i 's/^outline-style: dashed;$/\/*outline-style: dashed;*\//' {} +
```

Note that certain characters indeed need to be escaped, such as slash.

Comment: hmm seems that these don't work either, it's not writing to the CSS files, but they're not even putting out errors, which means they ran, but they didn't do anything.

Comment: @user94959 If the line is exactly `outline-style: dashed;`, both should work correctly. Are you using tabs or something that is not included in the sed?

Comment: @user94959 Note that this will also fail if your data has DOS style end-of-line characters. In that case you would need to either convert the files into Unix format or add the `\r` character in your `sed`.

Comment: No tabs or anything else, just spaces. Also the files aren't DOS style end of characters as far as I can tell.

Comment: @user94959 Where exactly are the spaces? In order for this to work, the line must look **exactly** like `outline-style: dashed;`, nothing more, nothing less. If you are not sure about the format, you can check with `cat -v file.css` and look for `^M` after each line.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about but the spaces are standard formatting for any CSS style sheet with inline code formatting. The editors I use automatically use auto-indentation which is just spaces instead of tabs. I'm not changing spaces in the CSS, only a particular line that contains one instance of a string variable that exists in multiple files. Try not to make this any more complicated than it already is.

Comment: @user94959 If the line contains indentation it must be included in the `sed` command! If you had for example 3 spaces indentation, you would have to include them after the `^` character as well or skip the `^` character completely. However, that would also match lines like: `foo baroutline-style: dashed;`

Comment: indentations shouldn't really matter for replacing since you're just only replacing the line after it that contains `outline-style: dashed;` only by replacing that with `/*outline-style: dashed;*\` Nothing to be replaced before indentation, only what's after it.

Comment: @user94959 please refer to my comment above. `sed` sees the entire line, it sees the indentation as well. Check `sed` documentation for the `^` and `$` notation. For now you can just delete those two characters and your script will work.